# How to bind datatable value in combobox which has static value?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox

I have a ComboBox with few static values.

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbBoxField" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource comboBoxStyleFixedWidth}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ></ComboBox>

MVVMModle1.cmbBoxField.Items.Add(new CustomComboBoxItem("Text Box", "0"));
MVVMModle1.cmbBoxFieldType.Items.Add(new CustomComboBoxItem("Pick List", "1"));
MVVMModle1.cmbBoxFieldType.Items.Add(new CustomComboBoxItem("Check Box", "2"));
MVVMModle1.cmbBoxFieldType.Items.Add(new CustomComboBoxItem("Radio Button", "3"));
```

When I am saving the data in Database table it is getting saved.

```
((CustomComboBoxItem)(MVVMModle1.cmbBoxField.SelectedValue)).Value.ToString();
```

Now when I am trying to Edit my form and binding the value again to combobox it is not showing the value.

```
  MVVMModle1.cmbBoxField.SelectedValue = dtDataList.Rows[0]["ControlList"].ToString().Trim();
```

Someone please help me in this. How to bind selected value to the combobox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few problems with your code here:

- You are setting the [`ItemsControl.ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) property to the default binding (bind to the current data context), which is incorrect unless the `DataContext` is any type that implements `IEnumerable`, which it probably isn't.
- If this is correct because the `DataContext` is, for example, an [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx), then you still have an issue because you are adding items statically to the `ComboBox` instead of whatever the `ItemsSource` is.
- Also, the type of items you are adding are `CustomComboBoxItem`, which I'm going to assume inherits from [`ComboBoxItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.comboboxitem.aspx). Either way, you can't say the `SelectedValue` is some string since the values in the `ComboBox` are not strings.
- You should really not have a collection of `CustomComboBoxItem`'s, but instead a custom class that is in itself it's own ViewModel.

---

Now that that's been said, here is a suggested solution to your problem:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyCollection}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=MySelectedString}"
          SelectedValuePath="StringProp" />

public class CustomComboBoxItem : ComboBoxItem
{
    // Not sure what the property name is...
    public string StringProp { get; set; }

    ...
}

// I'm assuming you don't have a separate ViewModel class and you're using
// the actual window/page as your ViewModel (which you shouldn't do...)
public class MyWPFWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MyWPFWindow()
    {
        MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<CustomComboBoxItem>();

        // Add values somewhere in code, doesn't have to be here...            
        MyCollection.Add(new CustomComboBoxItem("Text Box", "0"));
        etc ... 

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<CustomComboBoxItem> MyCollection
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    private string _mySelectedString;
    public string MySelectedString
    {
        get { return _mySelectedString; }
        set
        {
            if (String.Equals(value, _mySelectedString)) return;

            _mySelectedString = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("MySelectedString");
        }
    }

    public void GetStringFromDb()
    {
        // ...

        MySelectedString = dtDataList.Rows[0]["ControlList"].ToString().Trim();
    }
}
```

---

You could alternatively not implement INotifyPropertyChanged and use a [`DependencyProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx) for your MySelectedString property, but using INPC is the preferred way. Anyways, that should give you enough information to know which direction to head in...

**TL;DR;**

- Take advantage of binding to an `ObservableCollection<T>` (create a property for this).
- Add your items (`CustomComboBoxItem`s) to the `ObservableCollection<T>`.
- Bind the `ItemsSource` to the new collection property you created.
- Bind the `SelectedValue` to some string property you create (take advantage of INPC).
- Set the `SelectedValuePath` to the path of the string property name of your `CustomComboBoxItem`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `cmbBoxField.DataBoundItem()`? If not target the source from the selected value, i.e. Get the ID then query the source again to get the data.

```
(CustomComboBoxItem)MVVMModle1.cmbBoxField.DataBoundItem();
```

When you bind a datasource it is simpler to do it like this:

private List GetItems(){

```
List<CustomComboBoxItem> items = new List<CustomComboBoxItem>();
    items.Add(new CustomComboBoxItem() {Prop1 = "Text Box", Prop2 = "0"});
    //...and so on
    return items;
}
```

Then in your main code:

```
List<CustomComboBoxItem> items = this.GetItems();

MVVMModle1.cmbBoxField.DisplayMember = Prop1;
MVVMModle1.cmbBoxField.ValueMember = Prop2;
MVVMModle1.cmbBoxField.DataSource = items;
```

This will then allow your selected value to work, either select by index, value or text

```
var selected = dtDataList.Rows[0]["ControlList"].ToString().Trim();

MVVMModle1.cmbBoxField.SelectedValue = selected;
```